# Very detailed book for topological K-theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation, topological-k-theory

I have just learnt the first three chapters of Allen Hatcher's algebraic topology. And I would like to get exposed to some topological K-theory via self-study. But as a beginner, I am afraid of misunderstanding something and go astray if there is not enough explaination in the book. So I think a rather detailed book would be good. May I please ask for such a book? Thanks!

Comment: Atiyah's "K-Theory" is a classic. You'll get a lot of mileage out of the references at the bottom of https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+K-theory. I remember liking Karoubi's book and Friedlander's notes. I'd also recommend Weibel's K-book for a more comprehensive account of general K-theory.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Allen Hatcher also has notes on $K$-theory and characteristic classes. If you like Hatcher for Algebraic topology, you will like the notes as well.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, Park's [*Complex topological K-theory*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/complex-topological-ktheory/1C248AFD0F3AE9B0BE218F37D34D470F) is quite reader-friendly and easy-going.